# Connecting to remote Elasticsearch server with python's Elasticsearch package

Tags: python, elasticsearch, curl

I want to use a remote Elasticsearch server for my website.

I have used `elastic.co/` cloud service to create a remote Elasticsearch server.
I can connect/ping remote Elasticsearch server using the following command (it is scrubbed of sensitive info):
`curl -u username:password https://55555555555bb0c30d1cba4e9e6.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243`

After tying this command into terminal, I receive the following response:

```
{
  "name" : "instance-0000000001",
  "cluster_name" : "555555555555",
  "cluster_uuid" : "55555555555",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "555555555555555555555555",
    "build_date" : "2021-01-13T00:42:12.435326Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I am using the following Elasticsearch python client to integrate Elasticsearch with my website: https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.10.1/index.html#

To initialize a local connection, I import the Elasticsearch class and initialize an instance of that class by pasting in the local url of my Elasticsearch server.

```
>>> from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
>>> es = Elasticsearch('http://localhost:9200')
>>> es
<Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])>
```

Now I want to connect to my remote server using the same Elasticsearch class. To do this, I need to format the initialization of the Elasticsearch object with the info to connect to my remote elasticsearch server.

This is where I am having some trouble. The docstring for the Elasticsearch class is very opaque. In short, it is asking me to create a custom connection object and I have not been able to figure it out how to do it.

The documentation for the Elasticsearch object is a [little bit better][1] but still does not give an example involving a username and password.

I have the ability to create an API key, but I am not sure how to use it. An answer involving either an API key or answering how to connect using my username and password, would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to connect using [TLS/SSL and Authentication](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.10.1/index.html#tls-ssl-and-authentication) as described in the documentation.

In your case you should use something like this.

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(
    ['5555555555bb0c30d1cba4e9e6.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io'],
    http_auth=('username', 'password'),
    scheme="https",
    port=9243,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using elasticsearch v8.6, this one worked for me.

```
es = Elasticsearch(cloud_id='ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID', basic_auth=('ELASTIC_USER', 'ELASTIC_PASSWORD'))
```

cloud_id is different from url,